# Responsive footer falls too far below defined height

Tags: html, css

I want my footer to be responsive on small screen but when I shrink my window width, my footer second class (.pull-right ) goes way down the defined height of footer.Please guide me!

HTML:

```
<footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 pull-left">
                    <h2>Stay in touch</h2>
                    <p>Got a website? you want me to work on<br>please, feel free to email me.</p>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <h4>Email</h4>
                    <p>aisha_salman3@outlook.com</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 pull-right">
                    <h2>Follow me</h2>
                    <p>Follow me on social media...</p>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <a href=""><img width="36" height="36" src="img/twitter.png"></a>
                    <a href=""><img width="36" height="36" src="img/linkedIn.png"></a>
                    <a href=""><img width="36" height="36" src="img/insta.png"></a>
                    <a href=""><img width="36" height="36" src="img/fb.png"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-bottom">
                <p>copyright &copy 2016 | Aisha Salman</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #181818;
    color: white;
}

.pull-left {
    float: left!important;
    margin: 40px;
}

.pull-left h2 {
    color: #8e8e8e;
}

.pull-left p {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #6d6d6d;
}

.pull-left h4 {
    color: #8e8e8e;
}

.pull-right {
    float: right!important;
    margin: 40px;
}

.pull-right h2 {
    color: #8e8e8e;
}

.pull-right p {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #6d6d6d;
}

.pull-bottom {
    text-align: center;
    color: #6d6d6d;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Your `.pull-right` element is overflowing your `footer` element because of the `float` rule declared. Set `overflow: auto` on the `footer` to resolve this. Or, ideally, at those resolutions, negate the float rules and set the nested footer elements to display as `block` elements.

Comment: Change margin left/right in small screen

Comment: I've set overflow:auto  to footer but still it's causing the same thing @UncaughtTypeError

Comment: @AishaSalman I forgot to mention that you'll need to set the footer height to `auto` in addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.pull-right {
    float: right!important;
    margin: 40px;  // <== This margin causing your columns to drop in 2 lines.
}
```

You have `margin: 40px;` on `.pull-left` and `.pull-right` classes. So when applied these classes on `.col-xs-6` they create extra space and your columns drop. Either remove them or override them to make columns work properly.

*Note: you don't need to apply `pull-left` to columns in bootstrap. By default they are styled with `float: left`.*

```css
footer {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #181818;
    color: white;
}

.pull-left {
    float: left !important;
}

.pull-left h2 {
    color: #8e8e8e;
}

.pull-left p {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #6d6d6d;
}

.pull-left h4 {
    color: #8e8e8e;
}

.pull-right {
    float: right !important;
}

.pull-right h2 {
    color: #8e8e8e;
}

.pull-right p {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #6d6d6d;
}

.pull-bottom {
    text-align: center;
    color: #6d6d6d;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
    .pull-left,
    .pull-right {
         margin: 40px;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h2>Stay in touch</h2>
        <p>Got a website? you want me to work on<br>please, feel free to email me.</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h4>Email</h4>
        <p>aisha_salman3@outlook.com</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 pull-right">
        <h2>Follow me</h2>
        <p>Follow me on social media...</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href=""><img width="36" height="36" src="img/twitter.png"></a>
        <a href=""><img width="36" height="36" src="img/linkedIn.png"></a>
        <a href=""><img width="36" height="36" src="img/insta.png"></a>
        <a href=""><img width="36" height="36" src="img/fb.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-bottom">
      <p>copyright &copy 2016 | Aisha Salman</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: But then margin property is not working on full width of window.Do I've to use another property for this? @Muhammad Usman

Comment: @AishaSalman can you show me a fiddle as i've opened it in full screen and columns are not dropping, looks almost ok

Comment: No columns are not dropping after what you have corrected.What I'm saying is, that the margin:40px property is not working.But anyways problem has been resolved. 
Thanks once again @Muhammad Usman

Comment: Yeah now it's fine. can you explain this media query please? @Muhammad Usman

Comment: media queries are used to apply styles within specific view port widths. For example styles written inside above media query will be applied only when your browser screen will be greater than or equal to 992px. For more details about media query you can visit this link.. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 1):

Don't use pull-right, bootstrap have offset class for this purpose http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Try this:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-xs-offset-0 col-xs-6 col-md-offset-2 col-md-4"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

i have add some media query

```css
footer {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #181818;
    color: white;
}

.pull-left {
    float: left!important;
    margin: 40px;
}

.pull-left h2 {
    color: #8e8e8e;
}

.pull-left p {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #6d6d6d;
}

.pull-left h4 {
    color: #8e8e8e;
}

.pull-right {
    float: right!important;
    margin: 40px;
}

.pull-right h2 {
    color: #8e8e8e;
}

.pull-right p {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #6d6d6d;
}

.pull-bottom {
    text-align: center;
    color: #6d6d6d;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}
@media(max-width:1020px){
 .pull-left, .pull-right{
   margin: 0px;
 }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 pull-left">
        <h2>Stay in touch</h2>
        <p>Got a website? you want me to work on<br>please, feel free to email me.</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h4>Email</h4>
        <p>aisha_salman3@outlook.com</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 pull-right">
        <h2>Follow me</h2>
        <p>Follow me on social media...</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href=""><img width="36" height="36" src="img/twitter.png"></a>
        <a href=""><img width="36" height="36" src="img/linkedIn.png"></a>
        <a href=""><img width="36" height="36" src="img/insta.png"></a>
        <a href=""><img width="36" height="36" src="img/fb.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-bottom">
      <p>copyright &copy 2016 | Aisha Salman</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you! :) @Lalji Tadhani

Comment: Could you explain this media query please? @Lalji Tadhani